# Передача массива, как параметрa @Query в Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit, kotlin

Допустим, есть массив объектов `Rating[]`, содержащий 5 элементов.
Как его можно передать в параметр интерфейса запроса, чтобы на выходе я получил запрос `"..?rating=1,2,3,4,5.."`?
Используя Kotlin, можно конечно сделать `arrayListOf(ratings).toString()`, но выглядит не красиво, хочется именно массив передавать, как параметр.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно сделать [иначе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41590572/3212712) - передавать массив/список значений так:

```
@GET("http://server/service")
Observable<Void> getSomething(@Query("array") List<Integer> array);
```

чтобы получить адрес такого вида:

```
server/service?array=0&array=1&array=3&array=5
```

А вот желаемый вами способ, вроде, не очень стандартный, засим да - вручную преобразуйте массив в строку нужного формата